# jQuery Animate Callback not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to get this jQuery callback to work for me. Any ideas? BTW, please don't worry about the variables, I have a special project this is for.

```
$("#" + circle - 1).animate({
    opacity: 0,
    "margin-top": "50",
    height: '150px',
    width: '150px'
 }, 1000, function() {
    $("#" + circle).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        "margin-top": "50",
        height: '150px',
        width: '150px'
    }, 1000);
 });
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Can you create a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: It does not run the callback or the main parent function... This will not work in a JSFiddle, because it's just part of a much larger program. Sorry! :(

Comment: Try replacing "margin-top" with marginTop: <-- and don't add quotes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x2Ddp/1/  The code is fine, your problem is elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you have an issue in `$("#" + circle - 1)` which i am not sure what you are trying to deduct 1 from but I guess your id is a number which will fail with `NAN` during the calculation `"#" + circle - 1` so change it to `"#" + (circle - 1)` and try:

```
$("#" + (circle - 1)).animate({ //<- here use () to seperate the number calculation otherwise it will be NAN.
    opacity: 0,
    "margin-top": "50",
    height: '150px',
    width: '150px'
 }, 1000, function() {

    $("#" + circle).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        "margin-top": "50",
        height: '150px',
        width: '150px'
    }, 1000);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

For me `1` is not a valid ID, use `item1` and `item2` too for instance. Like this (http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/XSGN8/):

```
var circle = 2;
$("#item" + (circle - 1)).animate({
    opacity: 0,
    "margin-top": "50",
    height: '150px',
    width: '150px'
}, 1000, function () {
    $("#item" + circle).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        "margin-top": "50",
        height: '150px',
        width: '150px'
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: using number as id is valid with new html specs. Also btw this was my answer before your edit itself. :)

Comment: I wont't edit this time, because this fiddle is really working with all the counting and that:) And it was not working in IE10 with `id="1"`...

Comment: Don't worry, guys! I fixed it! Thanks, and goodbye numerical ID's!

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that your code is working just fine and there IS something wrong with your variables.  If $('#' + circle) doesn't find anything then nothing else will happen.  Here is your code working, slightly modified.

http://jsfiddle.net/qbtDj/1/

```
$("#mydiv").animate({
  opacity: 0,
  "margin-top": "50",
  height: '150px',
  width: '150px'
 }, 1000, function() {
  $("#mydiv" ).animate({
  opacity: 1,
  "margin-top": "50",
  height: '150px',
  width: '150px'
 }, 1000);
 });
```